# Selenium xpath element is not visible

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium. I am trying to execute my Selenium webdriver tests but I'm getting the following error.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

I am trying to click the tab 'My Proposed Events' using xpath which i got from the following code :

```
<head>

    <body style="height: 100%; background-color: aliceblue;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active" role="presentation">
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a href="#proposed" aria-controls="proposed" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Proposed Events</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:25px">
                    </div>
                </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: you can use By.LinkText("My proposed events") instead of XPath. Even after trying this if you get the error try putting some waits.

Comment: Looks you have 3 div deeper, try to use firebug to get xpath again.

Comment: I tried By.LinkText and waits, doesn't work for me, And i used firebug to get xpath again, its the same "html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"

Comment: I sometimes found calling the click twice to work on some elements

Comment: can you share page `URL`?

Comment: @Andersson The web app is yet to be deployed , i am testing on test environment.Not sure if you can access this url https://52.163.121.157:8080/Curis/index/toIndex.action

Comment: this page has a iframe#mainFrame and the tab 'My proposed events' is in there, and i am not able to to click on it using xpath.

Comment: @user3470987 both double click and calling the click twice doesn't seem to be working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Use following xpath to locate your element

```
//li/a[text()='My Proposed Events']
```

or

```
//li[@role='presentation']/a[@role='tab']
```

Add `Explicit Wait` until your element get visible and then do click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//li[@role='presentation']/a[@role='tab']")));
driver.findElement(By.By.xpath(".//li[@role='presentation']/a[@role='tab']"))).click();
```

Comment: i tried both the methods, doesnt work for me, still the same error "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible"

Comment: Can you try updated answer and let me know if having any issue

Comment: can you share your site URL ?

Comment: The web app is yet to be deployed , i am testing on test environment.Not sure if you can access this url 52.163.121.157:8080/Curis/index/toIndex.action

Comment: so first you need to switch into that iframe and then have to perform your actions `driver.switchTo().frame(0);`

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame

Comment: please pass correct index or locate that frame as your element is in

Comment: I even tried driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"))); doesnt seem to be working.  Not sure where do i find the correct index of my element.

Answer (score -1):

Xpath that you are trying to use was not correct.There is no div[2] element after div[1].

Try with below xpaths :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'My Proposed Events')]")).click();
```

Or try with LinkText:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Proposed Events")).click();
```

Use Explicit waits before trying to click the element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("put your xpath here")));
```